# EntityFrameworkCore 2.1.0 loads all related data by default without using Include

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with EntityFrameworkCore, it loads all related data by default.

There is no need to post code on this question, it's easy to explain without.

I have a Post class which has a User navigation property. The problem is, that every time I try to load Post, User gets loaded along with it, but I didn't want that. I'm not using lazy loading. I think that lazy loading is not included in EF Core by default, and that you need to reference a special package for it, right? Well, I haven't.

This happens even on most simple queries like the following one:

```
db.Posts.ToList();
```

And then, when I try to serialize those posts, I get reference loop handling problem because User again has Posts navigation property on it.

I haven't configured anything in DbContext or Post class related to database.

I am using SQL Server as database, and 2.1.0 provider version.

Comment: What are you describing does not happen normally, which makes me think you have some code that loads users in your db context. Can you prove that `db` is clean, e.g. `var db = new YourDbContext(); var posts = db.Posts.ToList();` and still getting `Post.User` property populated?

Comment: is the context still open when serializing? possibly lazy loading is populating navigation properties when serializer tries to access the properties.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro No, contrary to EF6, EF-core has no lazy loading as default. As OP says, you need to take a couple of deliberate steps to enable it. I presume the context life cycle isn't what is should be. Scarass, by not showing code you inevitably only share the things you're aware of, not the things that play a role while you don't realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but now I see that the problem was that my DbContext was registered as singleton.

Thanks to @IvanStoev